# How did this character return in Avengers Assemble: Secret Wars?

Tags: marvel, avengers-assemble-tv

My question is refers to only the **Avengers Assemble** animated series.

I just watched the **Season 4:Episode** 14 of ***Avengers Assemble Secret Wars: New Years' Celebration***. At the end of Season 3, we see that:

> Iron Man aka Tony Stark is left out in the other dimension and even Doctor Strange isn't able to get him back. But Strange creates a bridge through which the Avengers can talk to Stark.

However, in Episode 14 of Season 4, I saw that:

> Tony Stark is back and just hanging with Captain America in the Avengers' tower.

How did he manage to get back?

Comment: My gut feeling is ep14 is a standalone filler episode set in an earlier time period before Tony was trapped in the other dimension. But that is just a guess.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I binge-watched season 4 and it got me curious. Maybe you're right. Maybe they launched one episode for a Christmas/New Year special.

Answer (score 3):

Remy Lebeau is right. If I remember correctly, in episode 13 *"The Return"*, the Avengers that were sent to the same dimension as Iron Man (episode 2) built something like Bifrost, with which they make their way back to Earth, but it seems like the Avengers' tower isn't rebuilt until later episodes (and in a different world, even), so episode 14 timeline doesn't match with season 4.

[Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Avengers_Assemble_episodes) mentions the timeline for both the holiday special episodes (8 & 14) is from season 3, but I can't find a reason it can't belong to even earlier seasons. Either way, they were just separate adventures which didn't actually want to do anything with the story timeline.

Comment: This is a decent answer but would be a lot better if you could provide some sources (maybe quotes from the episodes) to back up your point.

Comment: Which part do you think needs more references? @TheLethalCarrot

Comment: Just something to back up that the timeline doesn't match. ~Re-reading your answer though it may be quite awkward to do that so +1. If you do find any supporting evidence though it would strongly improve your answer.

Comment: Thank you @TheLethalCarrot :) When I get the time again, I'll rewatch the episodes and add a bunch of quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Tony was found by cap in the 'beyond' episode  when the beyonder merged parts of different worlds to create the battle world in which tony's dimension also got merged to it so good news tony is found again